# How to show a local notification on iOS 7-10 when receives a notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, notifications

My app is receiving notifications from Firebase. When the notification is received, the app decides if it must to show a local notification. How can I show it?. I've tried this code, but doesn't appears any notification:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  // Register for remote notifications
  if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
    // iOS 7.1 or earlier. Disable the deprecation warnings.
    #pragma clang diagnostic push
    #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
    UIRemoteNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:allNotificationTypes];
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
  } else {
    // iOS 8 or later
    // [START register_for_notifications]
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
      UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
      (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
      UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
      [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    } else {
      // iOS 10 or later
      #if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
      UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
          UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
          | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
          | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
      [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
          requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
          completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
              #pragma unused(granted)
              #pragma unused(error)
          }
       ];

      // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
      [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
      // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
      [[FIRMessaging messaging] setRemoteMessageDelegate:self];
      #endif
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    // [END register_for_notifications]
  }

  // [START configure_firebase]
  [FIRApp configure];
  // [END configure_firebase]
  // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:)
                                               name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];  
    return YES;
}


-(void)dispathNotification:(UIApplication *)application userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    NSLog(@"Received notification");
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    [center getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:^(UNNotificationSettings * _Nonnull settings) {
        if (settings.authorizationStatus == UNAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
            UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [UNMutableNotificationContent new];
            content.title = @"new notification";
            content.body = @"show content";
            content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
            UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger triggerWithTimeInterval:1 repeats:false];
            NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
            UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:identifier content:content trigger:trigger];
            [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:nil];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {    
    [self dispathNotification:application userInfo:userInfo];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    [self dispathNotification:application userInfo:userInfo];
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}

- (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
  NSDictionary *userInfo = [remoteMessage appData];
    [self dispathNotification:[UIApplication sharedApplication] userInfo:userInfo];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? The notification is received, when debug the method dispatchNotfication is called and executed all the steps, but after center addNotificationRequest, nothing happens, nothing appears.

Answer (score 1):

I found it!

When put this code, shows the notification:

```
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler{
    completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement 2 different methods to handle local or remote notification. Look at the below.

```
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
        UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
        if(state == UIApplicationStateActive){

            NSString *message = @"";
            if([message isEqualToString:@""] || message == nil)
                message = @"local notify";
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"local message"
                                                                message:message
                                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:[[ContentKeeper getKeeper] getResourceForKey:@"OKButtonText"].Value
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
        }
    }



- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (true) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder"
                                                        message:notification.alertBody
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    // Set icon badge number to zero
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

Comment: This shows an alert, but, how to put a notification on the notification center?

Comment: when you are in app, push notification did not come up from above. if you want, you can develop custom pup up and than change the alert to do it.